# set score variable in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to set score +20 if users input the right answer. but I don't know how to declare it. I have tried this codes, but it doesn't work. here's my code.
            
            `score+=20;`

I have declared variable "score" at the top. please help me.

Comment: Please post the full code here.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work?? any error??

Comment: Please go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) once before asking question

Answer (score 0):

set score = 0 hope that help you solve

```
int score = 0;
score += 20;
```